# What is a hypergraph minor?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, hypergraph, graph-minors

Is there a theory of hypergraph minors? I could only find some attempts to define them at papers/theses, whose main topic was something else. What would be a useful definition? Does the hypergraph version of the Robertson–Seymour theorem hold?

Comment: Arguably one of the baby steps of graph minor theory is the Wagner theorem on planar graphs. Already this is highly non-trivial for hypergraphs. [Recent work of Carmesin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.04642.pdf) has provided a finite list of forbidden minors (for some definition of minor) for the embeddability of simply-connected locally 3-connected 2-complexes in R^3, but there are infinite antichains when these hypotheses are lifted. Related notions of minor towards embedabillity have also been introduced by [Nevo](https://tinyurl.com/y48qh5ps) and [Wagner](https://tinyurl.com/y3dcd4dn)

Answer (score 2):

I think both questions of the OP are answered in: [Hypertree-depth and minors in hypergraphs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397512008274) (2012)

> Let $H$ and $H′$ be hypergraphs. Then $H$ is a minor of $H′$ if $H$
>   can be obtained from $H′$ by a sequence of operations of the following
>   kinds:
>   • vertex deletion,
>   • contraction of (the edge between) two vertices that are contained in a common hyperedge,
>   • addition of ahyperedge $e$ such that the set $e$ induces a clique in the underlying graph, and
>   • deletion of a proper subhyperedge.
>
> For graphs, a famous result by Robertson and Seymour shows that
>   testing for a fixed minor is solvable in cubic time. In contrast,
>   testing for a fixed hypergraph minor can be NP-hard (section 6.4).

Comment: I don't think this is the Robertson-Seymour theorem OP is refering to. My guess would go towards [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson%E2%80%93Seymour_theorem).

Comment: Yes, I've seen this paper and in fact they even provide an infinite antichain (giving a counter-example to the generalization of the Robertson-Seymour theorem). So is this paper on cops and robbers really the best (and only?) reference for hypergraph minors? More importantly, is there no other natural definition?

Comment: I think this sequence of some operations you are describing only works in the finite case - but in the infinite case, I think my answer below might work?

Answer (score 0):

In a note concerning a version of [Hadwiger's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_(graph_theory)) for hypergraphs, I once defined what a *(complete) minor map* of a hypergraph is, and probably this can be used to define a notion of "minor of hypergraph". (If you are interested in the note, which I did not publish or put on arXiv, I am happy to send it to you.)

For the following definitions assume that $H=(V,E)$ is a hypergraph.

A subset $\emptyset \neq S \subseteq V$ is said to 
be *connected* if for all $S_1 \subseteq S$ with $\emptyset \neq S_1
\neq S$ there are $x\in S_1, y\in S\setminus S_1$ and $a \in E$ such 
that $x,y \in a$.

Let $S,T \neq \emptyset$ be disjoint subsets of $V$. 
They are said to be
*connected to each other* if there are $s \in S, t\in T$ and $a\in E$
such that $x,y \in a$.

A map $m: \kappa \to {\cal P}(V)\setminus \{\emptyset\}$
is said to be a *complete minor map*  if

1. $m(x)$ is connected for all $x\in \kappa$;
2. for $x\neq y \in \kappa$ we have $m(x)\cap m(y) = \emptyset$ and
   $m(x),m(y)$ are connected to each other.